# Issue - blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing app on phonegap, when i execute my app on Samsung Galaxy S4 and in sony ericsson device i'm getting the following error "blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse".

many click events are not working properly and on the above mentioned devices my app seems not working, no events are getting triggered and i get the error "blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse"

Please any one suggest how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a different Android Keyboard?  I have similar issues on a Samsung Galaxy Tab and tried the Google Keyboard instead of the Samsung Keyboard and the issues went away. Obviously not an ideal solution, but might help narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head with a very similar issue while testing on a Galaxy Tab 2. Here's what I discovered:

The error message in my console with tag WebViewInputDispatcher and value blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse appears to occur every single time I touch the screen, regardless of whether I click on a button or link. Therefore, this error message relates to onTouch events, not your click events as you might have expected.

When originally testing by clicking on one of my links, I originally thought the Galaxy Tab was blocking my link. It turns out, the Galaxy Tab 2 is just very insensitive to click behavior so when I thought I was clicking on the link, I was actually missing. By clicking slightly higher than I thought was necessary, I was able to activate my link.

To validate my suspicion, I greatly increased the font size of my link. With the much bigger link, I am able to click the link successfully on the first try, and my app now performs as expected. I strongly suspect that if you just make your clickable elements a lot bigger, you'll be able to click them successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem and it was driving me nuts. I solved it by adding a listener to a touch event, in my case it was touchmove, the listener executed e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); 
this solved the issue I was having but did not prevent the notices in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with samsung tab 2. I read it somewhere samsung's hardware acceleration broken webkit. The problem went aways after I turned off hardware acceleration in android manifest.